# Could marleyans turn into titanizable people if they eat the rests of titans?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In an episode of the last season of *Attack on Titan*, the daughters of Ymir Fritz ate the rest of their mother's corpse, and presumably because of this, all their descendants can turn into titans. What would happen then, if Marleyans eat the rest of titans?

Could Marleyans turn into titanizable people if they eat the rest of titans?

Answer (score 0):

No, they cant. Ymir was the founding titan and held the powers of other titans too, while the rest of the titans don't have any power nor the "IQ" so that it's user would have self consciousness.

Also, Eldians were a tribe and they "shared" the same blood and Ymir only had control over the Eldians and not Marleyans. This is the same reason that their armies had only Eldians as their titan holders.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would happen since the main source of the transformation power is in Ymir's blood. Only her descendents, the eldians can transform into titans, there is no side effects for eating the titan's flesh or anything. 
As we could see, she is the one who creates the titans in the **Paths**, and as we also saw, the eldians don't really die, they go to the paths. But with the last chapter, we saw that they are no longer there, everything ended after Eren's death.